# Для чего используют out в обобщенных интерфейсах

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с объявлением обобщенного интерфейса с использованием `out`

```
public interface IContainer<out T>
{
   ...
}
```

Никак не могу понять для чего используют `out`, по механизму это похоже на использование `ref` и `out` в методах или это из другой области?

Comment: Это для [ковариантности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`in` и `out` в интерфейсах — это [ковариантность и контравариантность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).

Благодаря `out`, `IEnumerable<string>` является `IEnumerable<object>`, а благодаря `in`, а `IComparer<object>` является `IComparer<string>`.

Есть хорошая статья на MSDN с примерами из фреймворка: [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd799517.aspx).

Comment: а если не указывать `in` и `out` будет в обе стороны работать? или такое невозможно?

Comment: @e1s Бывает ковариантность (использования более специфичного типа), контравариантность (использование более общего типа) и инвариантность (использование только конкретного типа). Без `in` и `out` будет последнее. В обе стороны нельзя, это сделает систему типов недостаточно строгой.

Comment: спс, начало проясняться